# Woocommerce: deleted single-product.php, everything still works. How is it possible?

Tags: plugins, php, themes, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to customize `single-product.php` to achieve the often requested **different categories = different single product templates**, but it seems this file it's not affecting anything at all.

It's like only `content-single-product.php` is doing what it should *(eg. if i customize it, the changes are reflected in the single product pages*) and the other files are useless in rendering the single products (!).

I even completely delete all php files in `plugins/woocommerce/templates` folder, and if i leave there **only** `content-single-product.php`, everything still works and every single product is correctly shown!

What am i missing about woocommerce's logic?!

Comment: have you checked theme folder for `woocommerce` folder, it's templates of woocommerce overridden by theme.

Comment: That does not work by default. You need to use the `single_template` filter to change the single template according to category/term

Comment: @ShyamMakwana.me it wasn't a woocommerce folder,because i tried to create one and put custom files in it in order to override standrd files, but it wasn't working. It endend up being the theme including a woocommerce.php file that is globally used for both shop and product pages – I think that when a woocommerce.php file is declared (which is required in order to make the theme WooCommerce compatible), the default template files such as single-product.php would be ignored by WooCommerce.

Comment: @PieterGoosen that's very interesting! Will it work in child theme's function.php as it is, or should i hook it to a woocommerce filter/action?

Comment: To be honest, I really don't know if woocommerce has its own hook for this specific function. I have never worked with woocommerce. On a normal install, the hook I've mentioned is the one to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because of a `woocommerce.php` file in theme's root folder, that was overriding a lot of stuff, including `single-product.php`, via `woocommerce_content()` function.

As redelshaap and woocommerce's documentation say, this is not the best way to implement theme compatibility and customization...

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

Themes can override WooCommerce default template pages, to customize the appearance of those pages easily. There should be a folder within your theme folder called `woocommerce`. WooCommerce checks for template files within that folder first. If a file doesn't exist there, it loads it's own template file.

**Edit:**
If you want to customize those pages, check out [WordPress' child theme functionality](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). Otherwise you lose your changes when updating your theme. The woocommerce folder within a child theme (if existing) will be checked first, then the woocommerce folder in the theme folder.

Comment: it wasn't a Mytheme/woocommerce folder,because i tried to create one and put custom files in it in order to override standard files, but it wasn't working. It endend up being the theme including a woocommerce.php file that is globally used for both shop and product pages – I think that when a woocommerce.php file is declared in theme's root folder (which  seems like it's required in order to make the theme WooCommerce compatible), the default template files such as single-product.php would be ignored by WooCommerce.

Comment: A `woocommerce.php` is not necessary, but a line with `add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );` in your theme's `functions.php` is. WooCommerce should then start looking for template files wihtin your theme's `/woocommerce` folder. Note that you have to keep the same folder structure as within the `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates` folder.

Comment: I tried adding `add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );` in child theme's `functions.php` but unfortunately it doesn't work. I created the folder `mytheme/woocommerce`, and if i put a new `single-product.php` there, it doesn't override the standard file, if i put a new `content-single-product.php` there, it does. The author of the theme included a `woocommerce.php` file in `wp-content/themes/Mytheme` root folder, and it seems like that file is ovverriding the normal behaviour of woocommerce's `single-product.php` file...

Comment: Since i would prefer not touch theme's files, can i ask you if is there a **woocommerce hook** i can add in child theme's `function.php` to achieve the conditional single-product template choice based on the category it is in?

Comment: It's true that a `woocommerce.php` file overrides a couple of pages. `single-product.php` is one of them, nothing to do about that. The theme developer should not use `woocommerce.php` this way.